# Ubuntu 14.04 libboost-dev and libbost-all-dev are linked to 1.54 instead of 1.55 which is the newest available version

Tags: package-management, boost

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and installing `libboost-dev` and `libboost-all-dev` installs `libboost1.54-dev` and `libbost1.54-all-dev` respectively.

I can also see that `libboost1.55-dev` and `libboost1.55-all-dev` are also available to my system. If I install those two by hand, it removes the `libboost-dev` and `libboost-all-dev` as well as all the software depending on them.

I am in an endless loop that the one package needs `libboost-dev` and `libboost-all-dev` (not specifically `libboost1.54-dev` and `libbost1.54-all-dev`) and another one specifically `libboost1.55-dev` and `libboost1.55-all-dev`. Installing the one reverts the other.

I would like somehow, to tell Ubuntu that there is a newer version of `libboost-dev` and `libboost-all-dev` (i.e `libboost1.55-dev` and `libboost1.55-all-dev`) and I think this will solve the problem. Is that possible, however?

Comment: If you look at the package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libboost-dev) you'll note it has a dependency for libboost1.54-dev; meaning there is a reason for it (as decided by the developer or packager). It could be it requires a specific API/ABI or something else, so you'd have to change that rule after validating there is no such API/ABI change between releases of the library.  If you skip that work and just hack the rules to allow it; you risk an unstable system, thus it's not recommended (unless you do the homework; work out reason for rule & decide you're okay & remember the risk)